What is chitta suddhi?
What is chitta and how it influence our current life and our next life ? What are the methods that can be practiced in our daily lives to practice chitta suddhi? Thank you.

Without being too technical, Chitta refers to the mind (for understanding technical and subtle differences between Chitta and Manas see this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28176/4732) .
Adhering to Dharma, chanting (Guru given) mantra bring purification of mind (or Chitta Shuddhi).
According to Dharmasutras of Baudhayana, sticking to truthfulness brings Chitta Shuddhi.

Internal and External Purification.
1 Next, the method of purification 2 Water cleanses the body, and
knowledge the understanding. Abstaining from hurting others cleanses
one’s inner being, and truth cleanses the mind.
Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 1.8.1-2

